# accessing Real Time SQL Monitoring in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, query-optimization, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle

In Oracle SQL Developer, I do not see Real Time SQL Monitoring, under the "Tools" menu where it should be.  I am only seeing Monitor Sessions, which doesn't seem to provide that visual information on the optimizer's behavior, like what Real-Time SQL Monitoring provides I believe.

**Details**
I'm using SQL Developer version 20.  I checked, and it looks like I have the required "diagnostics and tuning" pack:

[diagnostics and tuning pack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpEhW.png)

```
SELECT vd.* from v$parameter vd
```

I think that this shows I have that required pack, when I check control_management_pack_access.

I looked around in Preferences for SQL Developer, but I don't see any options that look relevant to this.

**Alternatives for accessing Real Time SQL Monitor**
Might I give up on this GUI approach, and try something else to use Real Time SQL Monitoring, like running this code:
`SELECT dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'ddga0450ycfsa',report_level => 'ALL',type => 'html') FROM dual;`

However, when I run that, what do I do next?  I've tried exporting the output to an HTML file, and opening that file in a browser, but it just looks like Greek to me:

[opening the resulting HTML file in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUcID.png)

I'm new to Real Time SQL Monitor, so I don't know what else I may have missed.